# Am I making a mistake using the chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative, diffeomorphism

I have two vector fields and a diffeomorphism, G, on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n\geq2$:
$$\mathbb{V}^i(x) = \frac{\partial{G^i}}{\partial{x^1}}(G^{-1}(x)),$$
$$\mathbb{W}^i(x) = \frac{\partial{G^i}}{\partial{x^2}}(G^{-1}(x)),$$
where $x = (x^1,...,x^n).$
I am asked to prove that $[\mathbb{V},\mathbb{W}] = 0,$
where,
$$[\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}] = (\mathbb{X}\cdot\nabla)\mathbb{Y} - (\mathbb{Y}\cdot\nabla)\mathbb{X}.$$

So far I have found that: $$(\mathbb{W}\cdot\nabla)\mathbb{V}^i= \sum^{n}_{j=1} \frac{\partial{G^j}}{\partial{x^2}}(G^{-1}(x))\cdot\frac{\partial{G^{-1}}}{\partial{x^j}}(x)\cdot\frac{\partial^2{G^i}}{\partial{G^{-1}\partial{x^1}}}(G^{-1}(x)),$$
and:
$$(\mathbb{V}\cdot\nabla)\mathbb{W}^i= \sum^{n}_{j=1} \frac{\partial{G^j}}{\partial{x^1}}(G^{-1}(x))\cdot\frac{\partial{G^{-1}}}{\partial{x^j}}(x)\cdot\frac{\partial^2{G^i}}{\partial{G^{-1}\partial{x^2}}}(G^{-1}(x)).$$
However, I don't see how these two can be equal and cancel to make $[\mathbb{V},\mathbb{W}] = 0.$ Is my use of the chain rule incorrect, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please write out carefully what you've tried. It absolutely will use the chain rule and the equality of second-order mixed partial derivatives.

Comment: Yes, your use of the chain rule is incorrect. What in the world does $\partial f/\partial G^{-1}$ mean? You must have derivatives of $G^i$ with respect to the coordinates $x^j$, so you have to learn to write the chain rule in a way that makes sense. And your formula certainly will need components of $G^{-1}$, as what you've written makes no sense.